# how understand url not reachable (IOError) ?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ioerror

There are images inside of folder names like Slide1.jpg,Slide2.jpg, until Slide20.jpg. But program doesn't know how many images inside of folder. I dont want to count them also.(lets say total number of images = 100). But when press nextBtn until Slide20.jpg program will take:

> Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never
>   Completed

When program Catches that error logically, it means there is no file name like Slide21.jpg. Which means total image number is 20. I want to go back when take at first time that error. Thanks for any advice

```
var totalImages=100;
var imageNumber=1;

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();


//************LOADING IMAGES TO STAGE********************//
//elearningau.com/nondynamic/
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://elearning.com/upandshow/Images/Slide"+imageNumber+".JPG");
myLoader.load(myRequest);
addChildAt(myLoader,1)
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);
function nextImage(event:MouseEvent){
    if(imageNumber<totalImages)
    {
        imageNumber++;
    } else {
        imageNumber = 1;
    }

    reload();
}

function reload(){
    removeChild(myLoader);
    myRequest= new URLRequest("http://elearning.com/upandshow/Images/Slide"+imageNumber+".JPG");

    myLoader.load(myRequest);
    addChildAt(myLoader, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for errors:

```
myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    // this means there was an error - do whatever you want
}
```